# pyzabbix get hostid from hostname

Tags: python, zabbix

I'm just starting to use pyzabbix.  I'm wanting to find a specific host's ID from it's name.  All the examples I read about do something like this, where the desired host_id is the first element [0] in a filtered (by host) list of hosts:

```
host_name = 'ci-dev'
host_id = zapi.host.get({"filter":{"host":host_name}})[0]["hostid"]
```

However, when I view the list of host with `host_id = zapi.host.get({"filter":{"host":host_name}})`, the first element is not the host I'm looking for.  Regardless of which host I'm filtering for, the first host in the list of hosts is always our Zabbix server.  The host I'm filtering for is usually way down the list.

What am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [py-zabbix](https://github.com/adubkov/py-zabbix), the syntax is similar but I prefer it.

A small sample:

```
from zabbix.api import ZabbixAPI

zabbixServer    = 'http://localhost/zabbix/'
zabbixUser      = 'admin'
zabbixPass      = 'somepass'

zapi = ZabbixAPI(url=zabbixServer, user=zabbixUser, password=zabbixPass)

f  = {  'host' : 'yourhost'  }
hosts = zapi.host.get(filter=f, output=['hostids', 'host'] );

for host in hosts:
    print "ID: {} - Host: {}".format(host['hostid'], host['host'])
```